# Cumulating values from all previous years but same month. (Powerpivot)

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have measure "A". Measure "A" already works as intended. What I want is a Measure "B" cumulating all values from Measure A for all previous years but only for the same month.
Example: The value of measure B for January 2023 is the the value from January 20+21+22+23 from Measure A.

Edit: Measure A is the result of various calculations including cumulations using filters.

Here is a picture with a pivot showing Measure A and below how the results of measure B should look like:

[image: Measure A and Target Measure B]

Comment: Despite not offering details about the data, the closest approach I remember is cumulative-total. https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/ Depending on the settings of your Date table you could use the <ALL( DimDate ), VALUES( DimDate [MonthName] )> combination,  or ALLEXCEPT( DimDate, DimDate[MonthName], DimDate[MonthNumberOfYear] ) as CALCULATE modifier within the <Result> variable.

Comment: I tried various cumulation formula, but the results are either 0 or definitly wrong numbers. Measure A already is the result of Filters and cumulations, so I guess that interfers.

Comment: In short, more information is needed to get a clear picture of the problem. Anyway, I am attaching what I was trying to tell you in my previous comment. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p5SgvqBqTlzyBLVL9hpPEgJtStFouu8a/view?usp=sharing